# Excel error dialogue still pops up even with error handling

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I seem to be having a unique problem that I have not had before and cannot find an answer through google.

I wrote a little subroutine to simply open a specific workbook that contains the word "Control" in it.

**Problem**: despite having an error handler that works, I get a pop-up box from excel saying it could not open a workbook.

Here is the code:

```
Sub OpenControlSheet(index As Integer)
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strFileName As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

strPlan = arrPlanPeriods(index)

ResumePoint:
strFilePath = "S:\Misc. Budget\" & strPlan & "\" & "*Control*"
strFileName = Dir(strFilePath)
ResumePoint2:
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("S:\Misc. Budget\" & strPlan & "\" & strFileName)

ErrorHandler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Do stuff
End if

End sub
```

Basically what the error handler does is manipulate the file path until the correct name is found. For example, if "92 Pol" did not work, then try "92 Poll." But before trying the new path I always get the following error dialogue:

"Could not open 'S:\Misc. Budget\92 Pol'"

Then it goes through the error handler and opens the correct workbook.

I thought if it goes through an error handler then I should not have any error dialogue boxes pop up. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: If I don't have a workbook to open I get `Run time error 1004 Sorry we couldn't find xyz is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?` (Excel 2013) without error handling and with your goto errhandle it works as expected.

Comment: You have some labels on the code which i guess you are jumping back to. Why not show the relevant error handling code? Specifically the code which attempts to direct execution back to the labels....

Comment: I suggest a more robust (i.e. not relying on error handlers as part of your code logic) approach is to use the `Dir` function to establish whether the file exists. Don't use error handling as part of your logic. Error handlers are 'error catch alls', they aren't program logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to resolve your problem.
The first one is use

```
On Error Resume Next
```

On Error Resume Next will execute next line of code even if the error is occur, Then you can check the error using

```
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
```

The example code is below:

```
Sub OpenControlSheet(index)
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strFileName As String

' Add this line above the code 
On Error Resume Next

strPlan = arrPlanPeriods(index)

strFilePath = "S:\Misc. Budget\" & strPlan & "\" & "*Control*"
strFileName = Dir(strFilePath)

' You will go through Workbooks.Open() even if error is occured
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("S:\Misc. Budget\" & strPlan & "\" & strFileName)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Do stuff
End If
End Sub
```

Second method is check that the file is exists or not before open the file.
As you use

```
strFileName = Dir(strFilePath)
```

This will return file name if it exists and it will return empty string string if the file or path is not exists.

Example code:

```
Sub OpenControlSheet(index)
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strFileName As String

strPlan = arrPlanPeriods(index)

strFilePath = "S:\Misc. Budget\" & strPlan & "\" & "*Control*"
strFileName = Dir(strFilePath)

If strFileName <> "" Then
    ' Path/File exists
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("S:\Misc. Budget\" & strPlan & "\" & strFileName)
Else
    ' Path/File not exists
    ' Do stuff
End If
End Sub
```

Hope this make you happy.

Comment: Thank you, I have decided to go with the second option. I am still puzzled as to why the error box comes up at all though, I've never seen it pop up before when using "On Error Goto"

Answer (score 3):

If an error is raised inside the error handling part, it is not trapped by any error handling code, and produces a standard VBA error message.

```
Sub errors()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  x = 1 / 0
ErrorHandler:
  x = 1 / 0 ' Error message will pop up here
End Sub
```

Now, using a goto statement (I'm just assuming you did something like this, as you didn't show that part of the code) will **not** get you - logically - out of the error handler. Take this example:

```
Sub errors()
start:
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    x = 1 / 0 ' Error will pop up here ON THE SECOND GO
ErrorHandler:
  GoTo start
End Sub
```

An error message will pop up, even though you can see `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` being called again. *No, it is not going to be an infinite loop!*

On the other hand, using the Resume keyword takes you **logically** out of the error handling part:

```
Sub errors()
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    x = 1 / 0

TryAgain:
  On Error GoTo TotalFailure
  x = 1 / 0

ErrorHandler:
  Resume TryAgain

TotalFailure:
  MsgBox "Nyekk."

End Sub
```

So, make sure that no error can happen in your error handling code part. VBA is pretty lame in handling errors.

Try stepping through my examples with F8.

Also, this setting can cause some strange behaviour:

[image: Break on all errors]

Comment: I used F8 to step through my code, that's how I know it happens before it even goes to the error handler. I didn't show what I do in the error handler mostly for 2 reasons: 1) because it's long and not really relevant and 2) it works. The issue is that before even going to the error handler I still get the error dialogue box. I hit ok, then it goes to error handler and the correct book is open. I have decided to go with what others suggested to just check if the FileName is empty, but nonetheless I'm puzzled as to why the dialogue appears when I tell vba to do something with an error.

Comment: Wow, strange. You could add a watch to the Err to see what's what while stepping through the code. Maybe `arrPlanPeriods` is returning in error handling state? Try setting `strPlan` to a constant string without calling the function, see if the same error pops up. The thing is, I can't reproduce the problem, so I really can't pinpoint what's wrong.

Comment: So here's the stranger part: I tried using the exact same code at home and the error dialogue box doesn't pop up! At home I have Excel 2016 and I think my work uses Excel 2013, so I'm thinking maybe it's some kind of old bug that I stumbled upon?

Comment: Emm, did you know `Tools`, `Options`, `General` has a setting called `Error Trapping`? Make sure it is not `Break on All Errors`. Let me add that to the answer.

Comment: I'll try this when I work on Monday and let you know, thanks!

Comment: @mifin So, any luck?

Comment: @mifin I'm still curious to find out if this was the root of your problem.